# got first record does not look like a TLS handshake when trying to connect to mailtrap smtp

Tags: go, ssl, mailtrap

I have following code for creating an SMTP connection:

```
func NewSMTPClient(host, username, password string, port int) (*smtp.Client, error) {
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{ServerName: host}

    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", host, port), tlsConfig)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("smtp client: tcp dial: %s", err.Error())
    }

    c, err := smtp.NewClient(conn, host)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("smtp client: new client: %s", err.Error())
    }

    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", username, password, host)
    if err = c.Auth(auth); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("smtp client: get auth: %s", err.Error())
    }

    return &c, nil
}
```

This code works very well with `Yandex` SMTP server. But when I tried to test it with `MailTrap` in my unit tests (since I didn't want to actually send email to people every time I test the code), I got this error:

```
smtp client: tcp dial: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

**EDIT 1:**

I have tried to set `InsecureSkipVerify` to `true`, but still got the same error; though the `MailTrap` configuration says that I should be able to use `TLS`:

```
TLS: Optional (STARTTLS on all ports)
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to connect to a non-TLS server using TLS.

Comment: would you please see my edit @BurakSerdar

Comment: There are two quite different ways of using SSL/TLS with SMTP, one called SMTPS which is simply SMTP _over_ SSL/TLS and one called STARTTLS which is more like a stew (or salad dressing) of SMTP mixed with SSL/TLS. You have implemented the first, but MailTrap is offering the second. These protocols are different, incompatible, and do not work together, so trying to talk with SMTPS to a server that implements SMTP+STARTTLS is wrong and does not work. See rfc3207.

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085. Would you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the SMTP server you are trying to connect to doesn't support STARTTLS.